# How to count empty accounts?

Tags: security, accounts, attacks, dos

Is there a way to count empty accounts using geth ? I just want to be able to track current DDOS cleanup process.

Comment: I believe there is, due to the fact that Vitalik is posting updates on progress. Check some of his recent comments to see.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is breaking some kind of Stackoverflow rule, but I'm going to go ahead and try!

[image]

When you have a database mindset you have a list of accounts

```
id    username    email
1     ramvi       ramvi@example.com
3     0x8000      hex@example.com
```

How many accounts are there? Easy, two! But for open blockchains there is no such list. Instead any account that can exist already exist, but with a balance of zero. If you send ether to an account "that doesn't exist" it will still work, and it will look to the world like that is an active account.

**Why is this**
You don't register anywhere when you create an Ethereum account. You just generate a public-private key. You don't tell anyone. So I could have been creating key pairs all the time while writing this, generating thousands of accounts, but you would have no way of knowing. Only if I use an account, will it be possible for other's to understand that it exsist.

So what is an account? It's just the cryptographic key pair.